# Anyway to correct the banner “UNPROTECTED” after installing NordVPN?

Tags: vpn

After installing NordVPN a red banner had appeared that says “unprotected” although the VPN is working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The NordVPN Status GNOME shell extension for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (and I presume for all Linux distros, not just Ubuntu) has been broken for a while.

I'll post an update here if/when this bug gets fixed.

As a workaround, you can install the VPN Indicator, another GNOME shell extension (included in the standard Ubuntu software folder).  This simple extension tells you that the VPN is up but does not provide any details as to which VPN you are connected to.

According to NordVPN Support, both of these plugins were not created by NordVPN not do they support them.  IN fact, I was told that they recommend not using them for security reasons.  Since the NordVPN Status plugin has been broken for quite some time, it's possible and even likely that the the project has been abandoned. The VPN Status plugin does work as expected (at least for me).

NordVPN has no "authorized" plugin that is certified for their service.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the banner they show on their website, that actually shows "Unprotected" at times while you are connected to one of their servers. There is nothing you can do about that. My guess is since they are constantly updating and adding servers, sometimes the website does not recognize IPs that have recently been added.

As long as you are sure your connection is up on your end, there is nothing to worry about. In any case, the banner shows you the IP they see, so you can verify if it is your actual IP or the VPN server's.